# Website not displaying the correct font

Tags: html, fonts, upload, cpanel

Good day,
I developed a HTML website but when i upload it to an online server, it doesn't display the correct font. I used a font called Futura Std. This font is not among the google fonts; there are similar alternatives google fonts but I wanted this. Can someone help?
Regards

Comment: have you uploaded font folder on your live server?

Comment: No I didn't. The font was just installed on my local server

Comment: please provide more information about how you tried to add and use the font

Comment: try to check the css by inspecting whether you get those fonts or not? compare your local and server css and font files?

Comment: On local, i inspect and get it. On the web server, i inspect and get the right font but it is not imported. Can you tell me how to import a font in cpanel? Probably that's the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Font was just installed on your local server as you have mentioned, that is why that font is not visible after uploading of files on some remote server:

include your font like this:

```
<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: Futura Std;
        src: url("../fonts/Futura_Std.eot") /* for IE */
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: Futura Std;
        src: url("../fonts/Futura_Std.ttf") /* for CSS3/New browsers */
    } 
p.customfont { 
    font-family: "Futura Std";
}
</style>
```

and include like:

```
 <p class="customfont">Hello world!</p>
```

Upload your font in both formats (eot and ttf) in a folder named fonts then just apply above css and this should work.

Comment: glad to know :) @Reagan